# Can we create the tag "Americas"

Tags: discussion, tags

[Plagues in Pre-European Americas?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/2872/961) got me thinking. It has the tags [south-america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-america), [central-america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-america), and [north-america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-america). My thinking was that it would be much more efficient to have one consolidating tag for questions that require it. The obvious choice is [americas](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/americas). However, the tag [america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/america) already exists, albeit it means something entirely different. I've proposed it be a synonym of [united-states](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), but it has not yet been approved. I tried to create the tag [americas](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/americas), but the system obviously wouldn't let me do it because it thought it was just a synonym of [america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/america).

Is there any way a mod can override that, or must we delete the tag [america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/america)?

Comment: Interesting. [tag:americas] seems to exist now. It has even been used on a new question. I wonder what happened.

Comment: The edit history says E1Suave added the tag. It might have been possible because no questions used "america" anymore, but you'll have to ask him for details.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, the use of "America" as a tag for the United States of America has the potential to be rather misleading (not to mention mildly offensive to non-USA countries in the Americas).

On a hunch I looked at the tag, and it was only used three times. Two of the three were also tagged [united-states](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) already, and the other was a very low-quality (negatively moderated) question.

So I've already taken the liberty of retagging all three of those questions as simply [united-states](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). As of right now, there should be no questions using the tag "America". **I propose it simply be deleted.**

That done, all that would remain would be to create the "Americas" tag, and then the problem would be solved for all time, because our software would prevent anyone from ever recreating "america".

---

Sometime yesterday somehow the tag [americas](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/americas) got created. I wonder how that happened. Surely Luke didn't (ironicly) do it by putting it in his question?

Anyway, I guess that renders a large part of this question moot. All that would remain to decide is what to do about the old "america" tag. I'd still prefer to see it deleted.

Comment: Does it take a mod to delete a tag in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If a tag is really needed, I propose [the-americas](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-americas). *The Americas* is the customary way in English to refer to the combined continental landmass of the Western hemisphere, and the definite article would prevent any confusion with [other uses of *Americas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas_%28terminology%29).

[new-world](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world) is potentially problematic because some encompass Australia and the Pacific within it (in that the Old World is invariably Europe, Asia, and Africa) while others find it politically incorrect. I have no problem with [western-hemisphere](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western-hemisphere)— if referring to the whole Western Hemisphere in contrast to the whole Eastern Hemisphere. It is not, however, an obvious counterpart for the continents of the Eastern Hemisphere, or concepts like [eurasia](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurasia) or [oceania](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceania).

Comment: My problem with this is that the "the" looks realy superflous hanging there on the front like that. Do we even have any other tags with "the" in them?

Comment: Nope, there are no other tags with "the" hanging in front of them. I don't see how "the" would prevent confusion. What confusion? It seemed pretty clear cut what the Americas were reading that article.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link; I meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_(word)

Comment: We're talking about "americas", not "american".

Comment: That's my point. There's only one letter separating *America*, *Americas*, and *American*, with concomitant risks of typographical errors and misreading.

Comment: Mothership advice to the SEs is that tags should follow common usage so that they show up in search engine results. Following that advice, it should be [the-americas].